# How can I make this notebook scale to the screen resolution in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently programming an application in tkinter and I want it to be usable on different kind of systems with low-end or old hardware. To make it easier for myself I will only support displays of 720p and up. The program is now kind of rescalable but the notebook element (containing 10 pages) is giving me issues. When the program starts it runs as a 720p spec not resizable window, and it has a fullscreen button.

The notebook code for not fullscreen mode (720p window):

```
itemsNotebook = ttk.Notebook(middleRight)
itemsNotebook.grid(row=0, column=0, padx = 20, pady = 10, sticky = N)

print(str(screenWidth) + "x" + str(screenHeight))

pageOne = Frame(itemsNotebook, width=652, height = 536, bg = "#333333")
pageTwo = Frame(itemsNotebook, width=652, height = 536, bg = "#333333")
pageThree = Frame(itemsNotebook, width=652, height = 536, bg = "#333333")
pageFour = Frame(itemsNotebook, width=652, height = 536, bg = "#333333")
pageFive = Frame(itemsNotebook, width=652, height = 536, bg = "#333333")
pageSix = Frame(itemsNotebook, width=652, height = 536, bg = "#333333")
pageSeven = Frame(itemsNotebook, width=652, height = 536, bg = "#333333")
pageEight = Frame(itemsNotebook, width=652, height = 536, bg = "#333333")
pageNine = Frame(itemsNotebook, width=652, height = 536, bg = "#333333")
pageTen = Frame(itemsNotebook, width=652, height = 536, bg = "#333333")
```

I understand what this part does, it makes the notebook a certain size on the window while not in fullscreen mode. My program has a button to enter fullscreen mode with a function connected to it.

The fullscreen toggle code:

```
def screenModeToggle():
    global fullscreen
    global blockScreenAdjustment

    if screenWidth >= 1280 and screenHeight >= 720:
        fullscreen = not fullscreen
        mainWindow.attributes("-fullscreen", fullscreen)

    else:
        tkinter.messagebox.showwarning("screen size too small", "Your screen has to be at least 720p (1280x720) to enter fullscreen mode.")
        blockScreenAdjustment = True
        print("screen adjustment blocked!")

    if fullscreen == True and blockScreenAdjustment == False and screenWidth >= 1920 and screenHeight >= 1080:
        pageOne.config(width=math.floor((1078/1707)*screenWidth), height=math.floor((776/960)*screenHeight))
        pageTwo.config(width=math.floor((1078/1707)*screenWidth), height=math.floor((776/960)*screenHeight))
        pageThree.config(width=math.floor((1078/1707)*screenWidth), height=math.floor((776/960)*screenHeight))
        pageFour.config(width=math.floor((1078/1707)*screenWidth), height=math.floor((776/960)*screenHeight))
        pageFive.config(width=math.floor((1078/1707)*screenWidth), height=math.floor((776/960)*screenHeight))
        pageSix.config(width=math.floor((1078/1707)*screenWidth), height=math.floor((776/960)*screenHeight))
        pageSeven.config(width=math.floor((1078/1707)*screenWidth), height=math.floor((776/960)*screenHeight))
        pageEight.config(width=math.floor((1078/1707)*screenWidth), height=math.floor((776/960)*screenHeight))
        pageNine.config(width=math.floor((1078/1707)*screenWidth), height=math.floor((776/960)*screenHeight))
        pageTen.config(width=math.floor((1078/1707)*screenWidth), height=math.floor((776/960)*screenHeight))

    if fullscreen == False and blockScreenAdjustment == False:
        pageOne.config(width=652, height = 536)
        pageTwo.config(width=652, height = 536)
        pageThree.config(width=652, height = 536)
        pageFour.config(width=652, height = 536)
        pageFive.config(width=652, height = 536)
        pageSix.config(width=652, height = 536)
        pageSeven.config(width=652, height = 536)
        pageEight.config(width=652, height = 536)
        pageNine.config(width=652, height = 536)
        pageTen.config(width=652, height = 536)
```

The numbers I am calculating are the sizes that look good on my current display configuration. I thought that deviding those numbers through my screen resolution and then multiplying them by the display size the program runs on would do it, but that doesn't work properly. The notebook stays too small for higher resolutions and too big for smaller resolutions.
The `screenHeight` and `screenWidth` are variables containing the height and the width of the screen using this code:

```
screenWidth = mainWindow.winfo_screenwidth()
screenHeight = mainWindow.winfo_screenheight()
```

Can somebody help me getting the scaling and resizing of the notebook correct? The way I have done it feels kind of like a workaround and it doesn't even work properly.

This is my first time here so if I forgot some crucial information please let me know.

Comment: resize is easy but you need thinking all elements positions on widget. Cerate event timer_tick , read widget/root width,height change somethings. Use this portal for every step information, got a lot examples, best regards.

Comment: you have too much repetitive code, you need to learn to use loops to create and update/configure each of the frames, especially since you configure them all the same, also there is no need to use `math.floor`, just divide using `//`

Comment: You can remove just about all of your code. Tkitner is exceptional at having widgets fit the window no matter what the size. Have you tried using the geometry manager options such as sticky and column weights for `grid`, or fill and expand for `pack`? In short, there is almost never a time when you need to explicitly set the width and height of widgets.

Comment: @BryanOakley so you don't need to declare a width and height in a frame function? I watched a tutorial about how to use notebooks and this is how he did it. I will check out tomorrow if I can make it fill the frame without declaring a static size.

Comment: @Matiiss I agree with you, this is not very efficient code. I wanted to try this at the end of the day so I did it the quickest way I know. About that //, I didn't knew that, thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @StartingCoder: _"so you don't need to declare a width and height in a frame function?"_ - correct. Most of the time you do not need to specify a width and a height.

Comment: you could keep `Frames` on list instead of using separated variables - `pageOne`, `pageTwo`, etc. - and then you could use `for`-loop to repeate some code for all `Frames`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb, you should not give a width and a height to a `Frame` widget. Instead, give sizes to the widgets inside the frame where appropriate (eg: for `Text` and `Canvas` widgets), and then let the frame grow or shrink to fit the contents.

The second rule of thumb is to design your GUI to work in as small as a space as necessary, and then use geometry manager (`pack`, `place`, `grid`) options to allow the widgets to expand to fill their area.

The following example creates seven tabs, each with a different background color for illustrative purposes. The window is initially set to 800x600, but because of how we added the notebook to the window, the tabs all expand to fill the window.

Also notice that as you manually resize the window, the notebook will automatically expand and shrink. This works even when you force the window to be full screen.

And finally, notice that even though we're creating many tabs, because each one is virtually identical we're able to create them in a loop. Instead of having variables like `pageOne`, `pageTwo`, etc, we have a single dictionary variable named `pages`. This greatly helps in reducing duplicate code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")
notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
notebook.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

pages = {}
for color in ("white", "red", "orange", "green", "blue", "violet", "black"):
    page = tk.Frame(notebook, background=color)
    pages[color] = page
    notebook.add(page, text=color.title())

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this tomorrow! Unfortunately I can't upvote yet.